# Checking Gtk.Image object's size in Python 3 and GTK 3

Tags: image, python-3.x, size, gtk3

I have a app that needs to display an object image in a Gtk Window, but I would like to make the window size esthetic to the image size. Essentially something like:

```
. . .
image = Gtk.Image.new_from_file(filename)
width, height = image_dimension(image)
window.set_size_request(width, height)
. . .
```

What I need is the ability like the "image_dimension" function above. Sadly, there is no PIL (python image library) for python 3, which would be very simple to use.

I am afraid I'm a new-ish programmer and don't want to go with header parsing (for example of a jpg file) in part because I would like it to work on any file.

Thanks,

Narnie

Answer (score 1):

Use `GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf` to load your image file. This lets you get the height and width, as well as many other properties of the image. Then create your image widget with `Gtk.Image.new_from_pixbuf()`.

Comment: I was reading that GkdPixbuf can only load in 8 bit images, is this true? Does GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf determine the image type? I spent a lot of time trying to figure out GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf, but just couldn't find any clear examples, esp for python (and I examined some examples from c, but I'm not a c programmer so it was hard to translate into python). Any tutorials for this? Also, is there a way to link image data in a variable to GdkPixbuf.Pixbuf? If so, how? I checked Devhelp which has GDK3 and find only Pixbuf which has get_from_window and get_from_surface methods only. Thank you :)

Comment: I found under the info under the GDK3 docs referencing the GdkPixBuf API, which I googled and found the new_from_data method, but you need to know the height and width first, which I don't know (unless saving to a file first, then reloading, which is actually what I was trying to do in the first place.

Comment: But if you load it from a file, then you don't need to know the height and width.

Comment: Yes, which is the work-around I'm using currently, but I would like to download an image from the web into a variable and the show the image in a window without having to save it first from the variable (I'm using Mapquest's static and directions API) then reload it, which seems a waste of resources and hackish.

Comment: Aha. But the image in the variable isn't raw data, is it? It's in a certain format?